# How can I remove myself from India's visa blacklist?

Tags: india, visa-refusals, bangladeshi-citizens, visa-bans

I am a Bangladeshi citizen. Back in 2013, I went to India with a tourist visa and overstayed for four days. It was due to a gout attack in my feet but I don't have my medical papers to prove that.

I applied again in 2015 for a visa, at Dhaka, and they refused my visa and blacklisted my passport, writing some numbers and date on it. Now I am not able to get an Indian visa.

How I can remove my passport from the blacklist and get a new Indian visa? Do I need a Indian immigration lawyer to do this?

Comment: If you could remove yourself from the blacklist, what sense would the list make?? Everyone would simply remove himself. - It is bound to be a lot more complicated, if possible at all.

Comment: You could try approaching the people who treated your gout and ask if they can provide copies of any papers they might have given you. If that succeeds you could try appealing to Indian immigration with an explanation and an apology.

Comment: How did you treat gout in just 4 days but yet cannot obtain medical papers?  What did you do?

Comment: After your overstay, did you get your status regularised before leaving? You should ask the officers at the High Commission. The Indian bureaucracy is funny but officers are easily approachable and willing to help.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/how-to-remove-my-passport-from-a-blacklist-in-indian-immigration

Comment: @Nelson: The treatment may have commenced well before the visa expiration. Details are important, because you'll be arguing that the overstay was outside your control, and you need proof for that.

Comment: As someone who suffers from gout - during an attack, there is no treatment that can be applied. You can take very strong painkillers that reduce the swelling, or drink fluids and flush your system. There is no cure for gout.

Answer (score 7):

> Do I need a Indian immigration lawyer to do this?

Yes, I'd talk to an immigration lawyer and have them try and sort this out. Any advice we might give here would be insufficient for such a complex situation.

Answer (score 2):

The 'blacklist' of those who reportedly violated visa rules or engaged in ‘undesirable’ activities during their stay in India are part of the Bureau of Immigration and Ministry of Home Affairs records, and direct contact with either or both will help determine what, if anything, you can do.

[Bureau of Immigration](https://boi.gov.in/content/contact-us-0?page=1)

> Delhi, Shri Prabhakar, FRRO Delhi
>   East Block —VIII, Level -2, Sector -1, R.K Puram, New Delhi-66
>   011-26711384 (T)
>   011-26711348 (Fax)
>   Support Centre:
>   011-26711443, 011-26713851 
>   frrodli@nic.in
>   frrodli.support@nic.in

[Foreigners Division Ministry of Home Affairs](https://mha.gov.in/MHA1/contactus.html)

> For Queries related to Visa:
>
> Pramod Kumar (Director-F)
>  
>   pramod.kumar64@gov.in   
>  
>   011-23077508
>
> Ashutosh Anand (Under Secretary-V) 
>  
>   ashutosh.anand@gov.in 
>  
>   011-23077509
>
> Pramod Kumar (Under Secretary-F) 
>  
>   pramod.kumar70@gov.in 
>  
>   011-23077506

Answer (score 2):

Only MHA Foreigners' Section has the provision to remove the name from black list. If you obtain a visa from Embassy but your name is not removed from the list, when you land, the Airport Immigration officer will deport you back even if you have genuine visa. Daily several passengers are getting denied entry and sent back on the same return flight.

Comment: Why would they issue visas to blacklisted people then?

Comment: @Hanky Panky because India

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply for removel to ministry of home affairs , foreigner department in delhi, only they have powers to remove your passport from blacklist..

Comment: Do you have references for this? Or maybe experiences?

Answer (score -4):

Immigration lawyers won't help. You might be able to convince the high commission in Dhaka, if you have proof that you had a medical problem that prevented you from leaving on time. There are cases where the foreigners office has been able to help visitors with temporary visas, if they face an emergency like a stolen passport.

Comment: I disagree that lawyers will not be helpful here.