# How can I verify whether my name is blacklisted by Indian immigration?

Tags: india, visa-bans

How can I check whether my name is blacklisted by Indian immigration?

Comment: I guess the most straigt-forward way would be to visit the closest indian embassy ask.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/how-to-remove-my-passport-from-a-blacklist-in-indian-immigration?noredirect=1&lq=1